# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' as required for computed enum member values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am getting an error as `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' as required for computed enum member values.` when I use conditional string with `typescript` `enum` operator.

here is the code :

```
export enum Constants {
  PRODUCTS_URL = "/api/products",
  BASE_URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "http://localhost:8080" : "",
}
```

following the answer from Muroleum, getting this issue:

[image: issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This or similar [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40793) with enums appears to be fixed, but the error persists nevertheless.

How about using an object instead of an enum? With these changes, it behaves similarly with some additional benefits:

- `Record<string, string>` type allows defining a string key-string value object.
- `Readonly` modifier permits only reading, not writing.
- Using `satisfies Record<string, string>` instead of `Constants: Record<string, string>` enables typescript to not only constrain your type to `Record<string, string>`, but further narrow it using keys and values you defined, allowing you to reference individual properties with autosuggest and get errors when trying to access non-existing properties.

```
export const Constants = {
    PRODUCTS_URL: "/api/products",
    BASE_URL: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "http://localhost:8080" : "",
} satisfies Readonly<Record<string, string>>;

// ok
let v1 = Constants.BASE_URL;

// error, property foo is not defined
let v2 = Constants.foo;
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'satisfies'.ts(2304) and Readonly' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693). using "typescript": "^5.2.2",

Comment: This is a good answer overall but I don't understand why you would bother with the `satisfies` operator.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - can you check my question update? here is the live reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwG4wLwwESKQgNiABwFsEwoMBuAWACgEAPAkAJ1lIFciYBhcaAQzIQYAb1owYABQBKAeQAiAVW4AVAMoB9RdIAyaTAHp+BAJYGCzEHHbAoEDABpxMAEIBBNQFEtu-djSo6FjIeIQkZBgwAPyYABZQUAQAXAYG+MD8uLEg0EkAHAAMhZFJmI60AL4wEPxQJhAAZiYIwtII-HDguACeADxtoMxwvdDMJmAA5g7VUGOTAHzz1DRAA

Comment: @user2024080 you are using invalid syntax. This answer uses valid syntax. Reread it.

Comment: @user2024080 I've updated the answer so it's more clear. as AluanHaddad said, you indeed were using the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a few ways to solve this such as casting or using nums, here's some examples that work in sandbox:

1. using string literals and casting

```
export const Constants = {
  PRODUCTS_URL: "/api/products",
  BASE_URL: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "http://localhost:8080" : "",
} as const;

// Usage
console.log(Constants.PRODUCTS_URL); // "/api/products"
console.log(Constants.BASE_URL); // "http://localhost:8080" or empty string
```

2. use numbers and conditional logic outside of enum

```
export enum Constants {
  PRODUCTS_URL = "/api/products",
  BASE_URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? 1 : 0,
}

// Usage
console.log(Constants.PRODUCTS_URL); // "/api/products"
console.log(Constants.BASE_URL); // 1 or 0
```